# how to make the users appear once while reading a csv file?

Tags: java, csv

I have a program I wrote that can read a csv file. The csv file have two columns one for clusters number and the other is for users. what I need for the program is not to repeat the user. Instead, to write the user once and in each cluster to simply write 1 if the user had shown in that cluster number.

**package parsing;**

```
    public static void main(String[]args){

        String fileName= "ClusterResult(final1).csv";//reading the file
        File file = new File(fileName);
        try {
            Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
        while (inputStream.hasNext()){
                String data = inputStream.next();
                String [] myArray= data.split(",");

                for(int i =0; i<=27;i++){// because I have 27 clusters              
                    Arrays.sort(myArray);
                    int founditem= Arrays.binarySearch(myArray, String.valueOf(i));

                    if (founditem>-1 )    
                        System.out.print("1"); //if the user name showed in the cluster the user should have one next to the cluster number

                    else 
                        System.out.print("0");

                }
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println(myArray[1] );
        }
        inputStream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
```

**the output of the program is :**

```
1000000000000000000000000000

ElDaddy

1000000000000000000000000000

Lxve

1000000000000000000000000000

Lxve

0000001000000000000000000000

ElDaddy
```

**where it should be for example :**

```
1000001000011000010100000000
ElDaddy
```

Comment: Not very clear that `cluster` thing. Show an input example ?

Comment: Could you post a sample of the csv?

Answer (score 0):

You say in your question your csv has two columns, if that's true, try something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> map = new HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>();
        String fileName = "ClusterResult(final1).csv";// reading the file
        FileReader file = null;
        try {
            file = new FileReader(new File(fileName));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            System.err.println("File " + fileName + " not found!");
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(file);
        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] data = line.split(",");
                generateClusters(data[0], data[1], map);
            }
            for (Entry<String, HashSet<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {

                for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++) {
                    if (entry.getValue().contains(String.valueOf(i)))
                        System.out.print(1);
                    else
                        System.out.print(0);
                }
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println(entry.getKey());
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error when reading");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.err.println("Unexpected error");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void generateClusters(String e1, String e2,
            HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> map) {

        HashSet<String> clustersOfUser = map.get(e1);

        if (clustersOfUser == null) {
            clustersOfUser = new HashSet<String>();
                    map.put(e1,clustersOfUser);
        }
        clustersOfUser.add(e2);
    }
```

What we are doing here is grouping the users in a `HashMap`, but storing the *clusters*
as keys.